# ng-repeate not displaying object properties

Tags: angularjs

here i'm using  Array for avoiding duplicate data for that i wrote this code       `if (EmployeeList.indexOf(EmpDetails) == -1)`  Here im Getting Error as EmployeeList of Array is not defind

```
     $scope.EmployeeList = [];
        $scope.SaveDb = function (Isvalid) {
            var EmpDetails = [{
                'EmpName': $scope.EmpName,
                'Email': $scope.Email

            }]

            $scope.EmployeeList.push(EmpDetails);
            console.log($scope.EmployeeList);
        }
        }
    })
```

Comment: there is array in each `EmployeeList `

Comment: Your `EmpDetails` is an array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: You need serious debugging skills.  it is `$scope.EmployeeList` not `EmployeeList` hence you getting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pushing array in array and in `ng-repeat` you're trying to get the properties of object on array. that's the problem. Try pushing object in array and that should do the trick

```
 $scope.EmployeeList = [];
 $scope.SaveDb = function (Isvalid) {
    var EmpDetails = {
        'EmpName': $scope.EmpName,
        'Email': $scope.Email

    }
    $scope.EmployeeList .push(EmpDetails);
}
})
```

Comment: tanks a lot for ur response

Comment: please accept the answer if this resolved your issue. Thanks

Comment: and please update your question heading. It's confusing. May be you want to use `ng-repeate not displaying object properties` or something like that

Comment: could u plz help me how can i avoid inserting duplicate data in my Array

Comment: you've edited your question. This will confuse the audience coz they'll see answers not related to your current question. Please revert it. and you can post separate question for this issue

Answer (score 0):

you are pushing array into array try to push

```
$scope.SaveDb = function (Isvalid) {
        var EmpDetails = {
            'EmpName': $scope.EmpName,
            'Email': $scope.Email

        };
        $scope.EmployeeList .push(EmpDetails);
    }
```

Comment: could u plz help me how can i avoid inserting duplicate data in my Array